# insert data into database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert data into database by using following code, but it causes an error that

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

I don't understand what can I do

Here is the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string con = "Data Source=Mir-pc;Initial Catalog=mir1;Integrated Security=True";
     SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(con);

     string query = "insert into [Resevation] name,cellnumber,guest,tabl,date values(@name,@cellnumber,@guest,@tabl,@date)";

     SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(query, myconn);
     mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox2);
     mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellnumber" ,cellTextBox3);
     mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guest" , guestTextBox);
     mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabl", tableTextBox);
     mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTextbox);

     myconn.Open();
     mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     myconn.Close();             
}
```

Comment: You are passing the references of the controls and AddWithValue needs a value. For example `mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellnumber" ,cellTextBox3.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = "Data Source=Mir-pc;Initial Catalog=mir1;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(con);

    string query = "insert into [Resevation] name, cellnumber, guest, tabl, date values(@name, @cellnumber, @guest, @tabl, @date)";
    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(query,myconn);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox2.Text);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellnumber" ,cellTextBox3.Text);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guest" , guestTextBox.Text);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabl", tableTextBox.Text);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTextbox);

    myconn.Open();
    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myconn.Close();             
}
```